# Assets not being run though the .erb preprocessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, erb, asset-pipeline

I am having trouble trying to `rake assets:precompile` in my rails 3.1 app. I keep getting the following error:

```
 rake aborted!
 Invalid CSS after "...und-image: url(": expected ")", was "<%= asset_path(..."
```

It seems that the erb preprocessor is not being invokeb but my file is called `style.css.scss.erb`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey Matthew, I see @vidbina had pointed an alternative to your problem. But just to ask, have you managed to get the ERB preprocessor actually working? I'm have the same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293878/sass-with-erb-wont-compile).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby documentation seems a bit unclear on a few things such as the usage of the `asset_path` and other such helper in stylesheets. Anyways this is what I did to get around the exact same problem:

1. I decided to do this the SASS-way by changing my stylesheet extensions from *css* to *scss*.
2. The image references in my code were changed from

   ```
   background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'blah.png' %>);
   ```

   to

   ```
   background-image: image-url("blah.png");
   ```

I found the necessary documentation on the sass helpers on one of the [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass)

---

I've also added the `config.assets.digest = true` line to my `config/appliction.rb` file because that seemed to get my output HTML to refer to the hashed filenames. Without the `digest` flag set to true I get all of my link tags starting off with 
`<link href="/assets/print.css?body=1" ...` or 
`<href="/assets/favicon.png"...` which pretty much defies the purpose of using the assets pipeline. Especially the *favicon* file will still be cached by the servers and CDN's along the way.

Explicitely setting the digest flag to true gets me 
`<link href="/assets/print-e47f5a48af04ce6854c840d74cd28fba.css?body=1"` and 
`<link href="/assets/favicon-15fb5e00d868940bc32db7996e10f594.png" ...`

Answer (score 0):

Change the file extension from

```
          xxx.scss.css
```

to
               xxx.scss.css.erb
and everything shoule be fine

Answer (score 0):

Even though an answer has already been accepted, and my specific solution may not have solved the OP's issue, this question was the top google hit so thought this might help someone else. I couldn't accept the idea of having to change all my stylesheets to use the SASS-style asset paths instead of ERB-style, because ERB should work.  After some digging, I realized that I had so many files with embedded ruby asset_path helpers, and I had missed one in the app/assets/stylesheets directory that still had just a .css extension (forgot to add .erb).  Also, I was including vendor.css, and that included one other file in vendor/assets/stylesheets that needed the .erb. Finally, I was using an older version of svn which still used the .svn directories at every level of the hierarchy, and since I had a 'require_tree .' in application.css, the .svn-base files may have been getting compiled as well, and obviously wouldn't be run through the erb processor.  Fixing all the above got me working again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `sass-rails` error, as discussed [here](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/94).

I had the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293878/sass-with-erb-wont-compile/14305274#14305274) and found out that the solution is by installing [`sass-rais-path`](https://github.com/quinn/sass_rails_patch).

This gets Rails to work SASS + ERB as expected, even though you may continue using the `asset_path` helper.