# Ruby on Rails: embedded Ruby not working in imported LESS files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less, asset-pipeline

I'm setting up a RoR application for the first time using LESS, and having trouble with some of the asset paths.

For whatever reason, when I reference an image using `asset_path()` or `image_path()` in a LESS file referenced using `@import`, it appears to silently fail processing the imported LESS file whenever I include an embedded Ruby call in it.

**Here's how the application is setup:**

*File-system:*

```
views
 -> home
app
 -> assets
    -> images
       -> general
          -> side_shadow.png
       -> home
          -> chair.png
    -> stylesheets
       -> less
          -> home.css.less.erb
          -> template.css.less.erb
          -> style.css.less.erb
          -> fonts.css.less.erb
public
 -> assets
    -> general
       -> side_shadow.png
    -> home
       -> chair.png
```

In my application, 'home' is the view being rendered. When it loads, it uses `home.css.less.erb`:

```
@import url("template.css.less.erb");

div#holder
{
    background: url(<%= asset_path('home/chair.png')%>);
    /* This resolves appropriately as /assets/home/chair.png... */
}
...
```

Then it loads `template.css.less.erb`:

```
@import url("style.css.less.erb");

...
```

Which finally loads `style.css.less.erb`:

```
@import url("fonts.css.less.erb");

body
{
    background-image: url(<%= asset_path('general/side_shadow.png') %>);
}
...
```

When I run this using `rake assets:precompile`, it aborts, informing me a CSS class I defined in my `fonts.css.less.erb` file is undefined, which seems to suggest it never got the chance to process my fonts LESS file.

However, if I substitute that `<%= asset_path('general/side_shadow.png') %>` for a literal path `'/assets/general/side_shadow.png'`, it continues without exception and the page loads as intended.

Why can't this LESS file (that was imported by another LESS file) include this embedded Ruby call? I can do it on the root `home.css.less.erb` file without issue, but not in any LESS file it references.

**My gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails' #, '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails' #, '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'less-rails'
  gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier' #, '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

- Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was pursuing this the wrong way; I don't need to use embedded Ruby to build asset paths, because there are functions embedded within CSS/LESS that allow me to build the asset path without using Ruby. This means two things:

- First, remove the `.erb` extensions to my `.css.less.erb` files (these extensions were messy anyways...)
- Second, replace the embedded Ruby call with the CSS/LESS equivalent.

  Instead of:

  `background-image: url(<%= asset_path('general/side_shadow.png') %>);`

  Use this CSS/LESS function instead:

  `background-image: image-url("general/side_shadow.png");`

This was not clear in the [RoR Asset Pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), as it appeared to suggest under the "CSS & ERB" section that embedded Ruby was to be used. However, the "CSS & SASS" section included the appropriate references to these functions. (In retrospect, SASS is a close equivalent to LESS, so this section of the guide seems more applicable for LESS.)

Additionally, this is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693226/assets-not-being-run-though-the-erb-preprocessor) with a similar answer if this post doesn't help you with your problem.