# Sass Syntax Error Invalid CSS when trying to add background image

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, background-image, sass

I'm trying to add a background-image in a 'css.scss' file. I keep getting this error:

> Invalid CSS after "...und-image: url(": expected ")", was "<%= asset_path(..."
>     (in /Users/caseyrees/Projects/citycreek/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)

This is how I am writing it:

```
background-image: url( <%= asset_path 'home/facebook.png' %>);
```

If I change the file extension to 'css.erb' it seems to work. I need this to work with the .scss file extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont want to write `assert_path`, try this, (from one of my working css.scss files)

```
background: url(image_path('footer_bg.jpg')) repeat-x center top;
```

and my `footer_bg.jpg` image is in `app/asset/images`

HTH

Comment: glad to help and thanks for accepting my answer coz I just now passed 5k :)

Comment: Could we get a small explanation as to why this works better?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding quotation marks around the ruby code like this:

background-image: url('<%= asset_path 'home/facebook.png' %>');

Answer (score -1):

It appears your ruby code is not getting executed due to it being in a .scss file.

My solution when I did a similar thing in PHP and less was to link to a php file which includes the real .scss file. Something like

```
@file:<?php echo($value);?>;
<php include("style.less"); ?>
```

And then link to THIS file, not your .scss file, in your document

Edit: if you need to have the .scss extension in your linked file, try @import-ing a .erb file

Comment: After continuing to search I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693226/assets-not-being-run-though-the-erb-preprocessor) which has fixed the problem. They referenced this link.(http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass) Thanks for your help.